# Most Markov chain definitions are false

Tags: measure-theory, probability-distributions, definition, markov-chains

When introducing discrete, time-homogenouos Markov chains $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$, a lot of introductory lecture notes simply seem to assume the existence of a probability measure $\mathbb{P}$  on the common domain $\Omega$ of the $X_n$, given the  distribution of $X_0$ and the transition matrix $T$.

(We need $\mathbb{P}$  to talk about things like $$\mathbb{P}(X_7=u \land X_{23}=v)$$ resp. $$\mathbb{P}((X_n)_{n\geq 0}=(s_n)_{n\geq 0}),$$for some $u,v$ from the state space $S$ resp.  a sequence of values $(s_n)_{n\geq 0}$ ins $S$, a measure $\mathbb{P}$ is required.)

Only one set of lecture notes , out of many that I've consulted, have in passing mentioned that there is a thing such as the Ionescu-Tulcea theorem that shows that such probability measure $\mathbb{P}$ indeed exist (hence the title). This theorem is interestingly is not yet on Wikipedia - only on the german [Wikipedia](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Satz_von_Ionescu-Tulcea).The theorem is way above my head to understand it, as it is formulated.

**My questions are:**

- Do we really need this theorem? If most lectures notes gloss over it, perhaps it is trivial that $\mathbb{P}$ exists?
- Since the Ionescu-Tulcea theorem seems to apply for general Markov chains, does its statement (which I don't fully understand currently) and proof perhaps simplify significantly for discrete, time-homogenuous Markov chains (perhaps if we additionally assume a finite state space)? I'd be very happy, if I could understand it's proof.

Comment: Definitions cannot be false. At worst, what you have is that the set of objects being defined is empty.

Comment: This is kind of a "foundational" result. If you're not intrinsically interested in such matters (some people are, but most are not), then such results are at their most beneficial when they give us guidance on how to keep things consistent, usually after having found an inconsistency based on naive results. In the case of Markov chains on finite or countable state spaces, they work how you expect, even after you iron out the details. So I don't think such results give any new insights, even if they may be laborious to prove.

Comment: Existence is not a trivial matter. The typical existence proofs for Markov chains are those that rely on Kolmogorov Extension Theorem to show the existence of Markov Chains for a given state space and transition matrix.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Suppose your goal is to construct a discrete-time stochastic process $(X_n)_{n\ge 0}$, each random variable taking values in a measurable space $(E,\mathcal E)$. The canonical approach is to construct a probability measure $\Bbb P$ on the sequence space $E^{\{0,1,2,\ldots\}}$ endowed with the product $\sigma$-fields, using the coordinate maps $X_n(\omega)$ to realize the process.

The Kolmogorov Extension Theorem asserts the existence (and uniqueness) of such a $\Bbb P$ with finite-dimensional distribution given by a consistent family of probability measures provided those  probability measures are "inner regular" (which means in particular that $E$ is a topological space with associated Borel $\sigma$-field $\mathcal E$...) One simple sufficient condition guaranteeing this is that *every* probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ is inner regular; for example $(E,\mathcal E)$ could be a standard Borel space. This regularity condition on $(E,\mathcal E)$ is met if $E$ is countable and $\mathcal E$ is the power set of $E$, as it will be for a discrete-space Markov chain.

The Ionescu-Tulcea theorem imposes no regularity condition on $(E,\mathcal E)$. The  trade-off is that  in the I-T theorem the finite-dimensional distributions need to be specified in a certain way by a family of conditional distributions. Not every consistent family of finite-dimensional distributions can be specified in this way (unless the state space is sufficiently regular—circle back to  the Kolmogorov theorem). But in the case of a Markov chain (on a general state space) the conditional distributions required by I-T can be defined once the initial distribution and the one-step transition probability kernel is given.

In short, Ionescu-Tulcea applies to give a construction of any discrete-time Markov chain. Kolmogorov applies when the state space of the Markov-chain-to-be satisfies a mild regularity condition. Both apply when the state space is countable.

To answer your final question, I don't think that the proof of I-T is  simpler when the state space is discrete. As there is no topological aspect to the proof, it is somewhat simpler than the proof of the Kolomogorov theorem.

Comment: +1, great answer! One small question: When you say "Both apply when the state space is countable", do you mean "both apply *in particular*..." (instead of " Both apply *only*...), right?

Comment: +1, great answer! Two small questions: 1) When you say "Both apply when the state space is countable", do you mean "both apply in particular..." (instead of " Both apply only...), right? 2) Are the assumption of Kolmogorov's extension theorem satisfied, if the measurable space $(E,\mathcal{E})$ is endowed with the discrete $\sigma$-algebra?

Comment: 1) Both apply in particular in the countable state space case. 2) Yes. Enumerate $E$ as $\{x_0,x_1,\ldots\}$ and define $\varphi(x_0)=0$ and $\varphi(x_n)=1/n$ for $n=1,2,\ldots$. This maps $E$ bijectively onto a compact subset of $[0,1]$. Now endow $E$ with the metric $d(x,y)=|\varphi(x)-\varphi(y)|$. Then $d$ metrizes $E$ s a compact metric space with Borel $\sigma$-field $\mathcal E$. Every probability measure on $(E,\mathcal E)$ is $d$-tight.